# SonarQube Scanner Error

Tags: sonarqube

I have recently begun running Sonarqube 7.0 from Jenkins using MSBUILD.

Several runs were successful, but intermittently (and now repeatedly) I find a failure in the execution.

The below is the final failure with the `verbose=true` setting.

Has anyone had this similar experience, and additionally, has any one found a solution?

```
    12:05:33 12:05:33.540 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
12:05:33 12:05:33.540 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
12:05:33 12:05:33.540 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
12:05:33 12:05:33.540 INFO: Total time: 1:25.012s
12:05:33 12:05:33.618 INFO: Final Memory: 50M/99M
12:05:33 12:05:33.618 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
12:05:33 12:05:33.618 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
12:05:33 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
12:05:33    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
12:05:33    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12:05:33    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
12:05:33    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12:05:33    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
12:05:33    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
12:05:33    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
12:05:33    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
12:05:33    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
12:05:33    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
12:05:33    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
12:05:33    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
12:05:33 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.rule.ModuleQProfiles
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
12:05:33    ... 38 more
12:05:33 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request http://sonarqube:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=CCGeneral
12:05:33    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:190)
12:05:33    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:124)
12:05:33    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:111)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerWsClient.call(ScannerWsClient.java:73)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.DefaultQualityProfileLoader.call(DefaultQualityProfileLoader.java:90)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.DefaultQualityProfileLoader.loadAndOverrideIfNeeded(DefaultQualityProfileLoader.java:69)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.DefaultQualityProfileLoader.load(DefaultQualityProfileLoader.java:64)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.QualityProfileProvider.provide(QualityProfileProvider.java:45)
12:05:33    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12:05:33    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
12:05:33    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12:05:33    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
12:05:33    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
12:05:33    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
12:05:33 12:05:33.649 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
12:05:33 12:05:33.649 DEBUG: Execution stop
12:05:33    ... 52 more
12:05:33 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
12:05:33    at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:227)
12:05:33    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:284)
12:05:33    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:240)
12:05:33    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:344)
12:05:33    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:216)
12:05:33    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:210)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
12:05:33    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.OkHttpClientBuilder.addHeaders(OkHttpClientBuilder.java:207)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
12:05:33    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
12:05:33    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:188)
12:05:33    ... 74 more
12:05:33 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
12:05:33    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
12:05:33    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
12:05:33    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
12:05:33    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
12:05:33    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
12:05:33    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:236)
12:05:33    ... 97 more
12:05:33 12:05:33.649 ERROR: 
12:05:33 12:05:33.649 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
12:05:34 Process returned exit code 1
12:05:34 The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
12:05:34 12:05:34.402  Creating a summary markdown file...
12:05:34 12:05:34.402  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
12:05:34 ERROR: Execution of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild failed (exit code 1)
12:05:34 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Let's see some research: Is Sonarqube up at that address? Is it reachable from this build server? Does this project key exist? Does this invocation use the right credentials?

Comment: The failure is due to a "Read timed out" (read the end of the log) when calling "http://sonarqube:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=CCGeneral". It looks like your SonarQube server is overloaded / under pressure.

Comment: I saw that it was timing out, but it wasn't clear to me as to what the timeout is a result of, or whether there is any remedy to influence the timeout period  (i.e. wait longer).  At the moment it seems that my bottleneck was the result of disk availability in the Jenkins server.  Same item has now run several times without failure following some disk cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my issue seems to have stemmed from a lack of disk space on the Jenkins server.  I freed some disk by clearing out some old/unused workspaces, and the job has run successfully several times since.